# QueryPerformanceCounter() Test for Windows Embedded Compact 7

Tags: c++, c, windows, performance, windows-ce

Loop through QueryPerformanceCounter() and save the value:

```
// Main loop for timer test
for ( int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++ ) // ITERATIONS = 1000
{
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    time[i] = double(li.QuadPart) / PCFreq; //1,193,182 per second
}
//calculate the difference between each call 
// and save in difference[]
for ( int j = 0; j < (ITERATIONS - 1)  ; j++ )
{
    difference[j] = time[j+1] - time[j];
}
```

(Divide by PCFreq gives time between each call.)

The high resolution timer/counter is supposedly working because it is not returning the default frequency 1000.

Average of 11.990884 microseconds between each time stamp (a thousand time stamp calls).

This seems extremely slow.

Is this test flawed?

or ideas as to why its reporting such slow values on a 1.1Ghz Celeron?

Comment: Why aren't you using QueryPerformanceFrequency to verify the reported frequency?  And exactly what are you trying to validate here?  It looks like you're simply timing how long it takes to query the counter and then do some math.

Comment: @ctacke: I am using it (not shown) to get PCFreq; //1,193,182 per second. Yes, i am interested in how long the call is to QueryPerformanceCounter - so that I can accurately measure other things. (+1).

Comment: @ctacke: isn't 12 micro seconds very long?

Comment: I don't know, that's over 80 iterations per millisecond.  I'd have to look at where that call goes and if it has to thunk to the kernel, but to what end?  Is there an actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @ctacke: Well, I am wondering if there is something wrong with the BSP...with that slow of a high precision time stamp call. I need a correct setup and hopefully there is not a actual problem I am trying to solve but this looks suspect.

Comment: @ctacke: If I run the same test on Windows 7 Regular desktop Win32 console application on a Core i5 I get 0.8 microseconds. that's almost 20 X's slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be worthwhile to eliminate the floating point math in the first loop in order to keep that (potential) difference between Win 7 Desktop and Embedded Compact 7 out of consideration. So, something like:

```
LARGE_INTEGER counter[ITERATIONS];
// Main loop for timer test
for ( int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++ ) // ITERATIONS = 1000
{
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&counter[i]);
}
time[0] = double(counter[0].QuadPart) / PCFreq; //1,193,182 per second
//calculate the difference between each call 
// and save in difference[]
for ( int j = 0; j < (ITERATIONS - 1)  ; j++ )
{
    time[j+1] = double(counter[j+1].QuadPart) / PCFreq; //1,193,182 per second
    difference[j] = time[j+1] - time[j];
}
```