# Is RDTSC() accurate if "SpeedStep Technology" is turned off on a Intel CPU?

Tags: c++, c, windows

Looking for the most accurate time stamp.

It appears the CPU cycle counter can provide that: using [unsigned __int64 __rdtsc();](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twchhe95%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

If I am able to turn off the dynamic CPU speed option, "SpeedStep Technology" on an Intel Chip (from the BIOS I assume?):

- Will rdtsc() be an accurate measure of elapsed time between two
  events?
- What will be the cpu clock speed? Is it be exactly the advertised
  CPU speed (i.e. 2.4 GHz CPU - use 2,400,000,000 per second to divide the CPU clock count value for getting the actual time)?

Comment: If you're on Windows I'd use `QueryPerformanceCounter` and `QueryPerformanceFrequency` instead.

Comment: @retired-ninja: I'm doing all this becuase QueryPerformanceCounter() is giving me a 10 microsecond delay...although I can subtract off that value I am not happy with the whatever counter it is using...

Comment: @retired-ninja: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896761/time-samp-test-for-windows-embedded-compact-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will rdtsc() be an accurate measure of elapsed time between two events?

No, not generally. It might stand some chance if you restricted the code to run on a single processor/core, but without that, differences between the counters to the separate processors/cores can lead to erroneous results.

> What will be the cpu clock speed? Is it be exactly the advertised CPU speed (i.e. 2.4 GHz CPU - use 2,400,000,000 per second to divide the CPU clock count value for getting the actual time)?

Most machines allow the user to adjust the clock speed in the BIOS setup. Depending on the environment in which your code is running you may have access to the motherboard's 1.024 MHz clock, which is constant regardless of CPU clock speed. If you can read it, that can give you a solid basis for determining the rate you're getting on the time-stamp counter.